# MongoDB - using Mongoose schema - how to tell Mongoose not to save particular field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Say I have a Mongoose schema that looks like this:

```
userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        username: {
            type: String,
            isUnique: true,
            required: true
        },
        teamSnap: {
            username: String,
            password: String
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        linkedin_id: Number,
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        numberOfLineupsCreated: Number,
        hasPaidAlready: Boolean,
        longitude: Number,
        registered_at: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        },
        created_at: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        },
        updated_at: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        }
    });
```

how do I tell Mongoose NOT to save/store the teamSnap field in the database?

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to do that you want a field in the schema that isn't persisted to the database?

Comment: well, you're probably right, this could be put into session/cookie data instead

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to persist a field in the database why do you need in your model class ?

You can add it later to the object that you query from MongoDB.

```
db.users.findOne({id: id}, function(err, user) {
  user.teamSnap = value
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could redefine the `toJSON()` method and remove your field there:

```
UserSchema.methods.toJSON = function() {
    var obj = this.toObject()
    delete obj.teamSnap

    return obj
}
```